# Node.js ssh2-sftp-client Error: fastPut: No response from server Local

Tags: node.js, ssh2, ssh2-sftp-client

I am using `node -v v14.17.0` and `"ssh2-sftp-client": "^7.0.0"` and method `fastPut` https://github.com/theophilusx/ssh2-sftp-client#sec-5-2-9

Checking the remote files is okay, so connection works.

My environment is `wsl2 Ubuntu-20.04`

Problem I face is error

```
RuntimeError: abort(Error: fastPut: No response from server Local: /home/draganddrop/testi.txt Remote: Downloads/testi.txt). Build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 for more info.
    at process.J (/home/draganddrop/node_modules/ssh2/lib/protocol/crypto/poly1305.js:20:53)
    at process.emit (events.js:376:20)
    at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:245:33)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:96:32)
```

I have tried also with `sftp> put /home/draganddrop/testi.txt Downloads/testi.txt` from console, which works.

Code I am using:

```
        let Client = require('ssh2-sftp-client');
        let sftp = new Client();
    
        let remotePath = 'Downloads/testi.txt';
        let localPath = '/home/draganddrop/testi.txt'

        const config = {
          host: 'XX.XX.XXX.XXX',
          port: '22',
          username: 'XXXXX',
          password: 'XXXXXX'
        };

        sftp.connect(config)
        .then(() => {
          sftp.fastPut(localPath, remotePath);
          //return sftp.exists(remotePath);
        })
        //.then(data => {
        //  console.log(data);          // will be false or d, -, l (dir, file or link)
        //})
        .then(() => {
          sftp.end();
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.error(err.message);
        });
```

I have no idea what causes this error, I've tried with different paths and get either bad path error or this. What could be the cause?

Comment: Hi @eemilk, looks like the problem in asynchronous function fastPut and second `then`, it close connecting before put the file, try to return promise in first then `return sftp.fastPut(localPath, remotePath);`

Comment: @PavloNaumenko This seem to have done the trick.

Comment: I wrote the same in the answer

Comment: Please help on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72277310/node-js-ssh2-sftp-client-error-fastput-unhandledpromiserejectionwarning-error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for the problem is that the connection is closing before the finish of executing `fastPut`.
You are running connect, after that in the first `.then`, the method `fastPut` runs asynchronously, it doesn't wait for the finish execution and return undefined to the next method `.then` of the chain.
To solve the problem you just need to return a promise received from `fastPut`

```
sftp.connect(config)
        .then(() => sftp.fastPut(localPath, remotePath))
        .then((data) => {/* do something*/}
        .finally(() => sftp.end())
```

Comment: First 'then' should return?  return sftp.fastPut....

Comment: Sorry @BertC, I didn't get the question. Callback in first `then` is arrow function expression, so it returns result of `sftp.fastPut`

Comment: Yes @Pavlo, you are absolutely right. I missed the missing curly braces. Sorry for that.

Comment: please help on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72277310/node-js-ssh2-sftp-client-error-fastput-unhandledpromiserejectionwarning-error